# Parsing postdata value in nodejs

Tags: node.js, parsing, post, connect

I have a post data in the format below

```
authInfo={"user":"1","password":"a"}
```

How do I get the key ie authInfo. I am stuck here! `req.query` did not work out. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Data transmitted via POST could be found in `req.body`.

For your example:

`req.body.authInfo`

Also: You need a data parser enabled, otherwise the Post data will not be decoded. I assume you use express, so you would need `app.use(express.bodyParser())`.

Comment: I use connect.I wont know the key i need to retrieve that from the post data.

Comment: @AmandaG express is based on connect, so there is not much of a difference. Have a look at their documentation for `bodyParser`: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var authInfo = {"user":"1","password":"a"}
var user = authInfo.user
var pass = authInfo.password

// user = 1 , pass = a
```

Comment: The problem Amanda has is to recover the data from a POST request, not from the JSON. The answer of TheHippo is correct, you need a bodyParser in order to retrieve data from the POST JSON